# Running warpPerspective on multiple Matrices using the same homography matrix

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to adapt a background subtraction [algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.364.4347&rep=rep1&type=pdf) to a PTZ camera. This requires me to constantly adapt my background model to the new position of the camera, using a homograpy matrix to warp the model.

My problem is the following : I have a homography matrix H that I need to apply to a moderate number (~20) of cv::Mats that represent my background model.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> models; // my bg model
cv::Mat H; // homography matrix
for(size_t i = 0; i < models.size(); ++i)
{
    warpPerspective(models[i], models[i], H, models[i].size(),
                    INTER_NEAREST | WARP_INVERSE_MAP);
}
```

This operation takes ~250ms which is way too much for realtime processing which I want to do.

My question is : what can I do to reduce this time ? Could [remap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4) be used to replace warpPerspective ? If yes, how ?

Comment: remap should be possible, but not sure whether it will be faster. If your system has any graphics card, using openGL might be an option, too. Maybe you can even exploit texture coordinates for homogrsphy warping.

Comment: @Micka : I hoped someone would have an idea about how to optimise warpPerspective for multiple matrices but OpenGL is indeed an option, thanks for the idea.